# Centering a FIXED div inside its "parent"

Tags: css, css-position

I swear I have checked quite thoroughly before posting this!
I am trying to center a FIXED div inside its parent div.

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 400px; /* so it's fluid*/
  background: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  /* center the div */
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  min-height: 10em;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #af0000;
}
```

I wonder if it s possible to do with pure CSS. I can calculate the remaining space, divide it by two and change LEFT and RIGHT (i.e left: 6px; right: 6px; etc..) with JQuery but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/PvfFy/980/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: WBT - you won't find solution for the mentioned above problem there. Thanks anyway, man

Comment: So `#main`'s width varies? Or is setting an explicit width on it an option?

Comment: that's one of the biggest problems - it is fluid so, yes - it does vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and [`vw` (viewer width)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

We can calculate measurements in CSS using this powerful addition to CSS, and combined with `vw` (and also `vh`) we can position elements quite precisely and responsively.

```css
#main {
  height: 200vh; /* force scrolling for demo */
}
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  left: calc( 50vw - 150px ); /* this is the magic */
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

### Since question was clarified (sorry for not paying closer attention)

Using [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning):

> ...will behave just like a relatively positioned element until the viewport scrolls...

Unfortunately it is <sup>(`June 25, '17`)</sup> [less than well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky), but allows us to use `margin: 0 auto;` centering since `#fixed` is of a fixed `width`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#main {
  min-width: 400px; /* variable width */
  width: 70vw;      /* for demo */
  height: 200vh;
  background: rgba( 0, 255, 0, 0.2 );
}
#fixed {
  position: sticky; /* this is the magic */
  margin: 0 auto;   /* along with this */
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  background: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rossitten - Is there something about it you don't like; something not working the way you need?

Comment: I have set a specific width for #main (as teh main is fluid it coudl be anything from, say 400px to 600px and evertwhere between #fixed div must be centered) and the #fixed is not centered anymore

Comment: @Rossitten - Will the fixed (300px) width of `#fixed` always be less than the width of `#main`?

Comment: @Rossitten - updated with alternative using `position:sticky`.

Comment: Basically - #main is site's right column. #fixed is a banner that is supposed to be always visible when scroll is used (=  sticky)
it is well centered before its position is changed to "fixed".

Comment: sticky, indeed, does what it should...in FF
please check the support of this: http://caniuse.com/css-sticky/embed/

Comment: it is a nice solution though! Thank you
you see-  looks like this, from the first sight, easy task has proved to be quite a tricky one...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147539/discussion-between-fred-gandt-and-rossitten).

Answer (score 2):

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 10em;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #af0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could be exactly what I am looking fro but... does not work in IE

Comment: Is fine in IE11. Not sure how far you want to go back in time. https://venturebeat.com/2016/01/12/microsoft-ends-support-for-ie8-ie9-ie10-and-windows-8/

Comment: Changing the specs from min-width to width. Maybe a good idea to post here what you really need.

Comment: I'd like to have it always centered. 400px - center, 500px - center...setting fixed width was done with purpose to check if it will work well with a particular width.

Comment: I just looked at this in IE v11.0.96... and `#fixed` looked to have its top, left corner at the center of `#main`. I was looking at [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex) and there's a horror show of a bug list for IE, but there's also [a load of stuff on github](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) suggesting workarounds. It would be a shame if this answer can't be forced to work x-browser.

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer.

I got this idea from [Fred's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44743568/8157693)  if it brings you closer go upvote his answer and not this one.

This doesn't seem to work in the viewer below unless you **use fullscreen** for some reason.

Maybe this will bring you closer.

You `#main` needs `position: relative`

And your `#fixed` needs `position: sticky` As well as `top: 25%` `bottom: 25%` `left: 50%` `right: 50%`

See example below:

```css
/* start eesential CSS */

#main {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 300vh;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

#fixed {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: sticky;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}


/* end eesential CSS */


/* Start style fluff */

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
  background: darkred;
}

#fixed {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  color: #999;
  background: darkblue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#fixed *,
#none-fixed * {
  padding: 25px;
  color: #999;
}


/* End style fluff */
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="none-fixed">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolore persius at nam, ne audiam meliore quo. Vis no lobortis referrentur, ex per modo epicuri oportere. Ad primis pertinacia deterruisset eam Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an utinam dolorum vix, usu no sumo quaeque molestiae.
      Pro mundi nemore at, tation ceteros repudiare ut eos. Usu latine ponderum deseruisse no, has doctus propriae cu. Et vim unum saepe, an commune adversarium duo. Mea ea legere doming probatus, alia mutat te ius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an utinam
      dolorum vix, usu no sumo quaeque molestiae. Pro mundi nemore at, tation ceteros repudiare ut eos. Usu latine ponderum deseruisse no, has doctus propriae cu. Et vim unum saepe, an commune adversarium duo. Mea ea legere doming probatus, alia mutat
      te ius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolore persius at nam, ne audiam meliore quo. Vis no lobortis referrentur, ex per modo epicuri oportere. Ad primis pertinacia deterruisset eam Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an utinam dolorum vix, usu no sumo quaeque
      molestiae. Pro mundi nemore at, tation ceteros repudiare ut eos. Usu latine ponderum deseruisse no, has doctus propriae cu. Et vim unum saepe, an commune adversarium duo. Mea ea legere doming probatus, alia mutat te ius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      an utinam dolorum vix, usu no sumo quaeque molestiae. Pro mundi nemore at, tation ceteros repudiare ut eos. Usu latine ponderum deseruisse no, has doctus propriae cu. Et vim unum saepe, an commune adversarium duo. Mea ea legere doming probatus,
      alia mutat te ius.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="fixed">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolore persius at nam, ne audiam meliore quo. Vis no lobortis referrentur, ex per modo epicuri oportere. Ad primis pertinacia deterruisset eam Lore molestiae. Pro mundi nemore at, tation
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="none-fixed">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolore persius at nam, ne audiam meliore quo. Vis no lobortis referrentur, ex per modo epicuri oportere. Ad primis pertinacia deterruisset eam Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an utinam dolorum vix, usu no sumo quaeque molestiae.
      Pro mundi nemore at, tation ceteros repudiare ut eos. Usu latine ponderum deseruisse no, has doctus propriae cu. Et vim unum saepe, an commune adversarium duo. Mea ea legere doming probatus, alia mutat te ius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an utinam
      dolorum vix, usu no sumo quaeque molestiae. Pro mundi nemore at, tation ceteros repudiare ut eos. Usu latine ponderum deseruisse no, has doctus propriae cu. Et vim unum saepe, an commune adversarium duo. Mea ea legere doming probatus, alia mutat
      a deterruisset eam Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an utinam dolorum vix, usu no sumo quaeque molestiae. Pro mundi nemore at, tation ceteros repudiare ut eos. Usu latine ponderum deseruisse no, has doctus propriae cu. Et vim unum saepe, an commune adversarium
      duo. Mea ea legere doming probatus, alia mutat te ius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an utinam dolorum vix, usu no sumo quaeque molestiae. Pro mundi nemore at, tation ceteros repudiare ut eos. Usu latine ponderum deseruisse no, has doctus propriae
      cu. Et vim unum saepe, an commune adversarium duo. Mea ea legere doming probatus, alia mutat te ius. te ius.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="none-fixed">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolore persius at nam, ne audiam meliore quo. Vis no lobortis referrentur, ex per modo epicuri oportere. Ad primis pertinacia deterruisset eam Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an utinam dolorum vix, usu no sumo quaeque molestiae.
      Pro mundi nemore at, tation ceteros repudiare ut eos. Usu latine ponderum deseruisse no, has doctus propriae cu. Et vim unum saepe, an commune adversarium duo. Mea ea legere doming probatus, alia mutat te ius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an utinam
      dolorum vix, usu no sumo quaeque molestiae. Pro mundi nemore at, tation ceteros repudiare ut eos. Usu latine ponderum deseruisse no, has doctus propriae cu. Et vim unum saepe, an commune adversarium duo. Mea ea legere doming probatus, alia mutat
      te ius.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rossitten Not sure what you mean. It's in the center vertically and horizontally. Could please explain?

Comment: it is not fixed now. Must be fixed and stay at the same position when scrolling.

Comment: @Rossitten I edited the answer. I cannot seem to get it to work with the default viewer window here. It seams to work fine when opened in full screen.

Comment: position: sticky does not work in IE (in any of that bloody browser) so this won't work, I am afraid =((( thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: No problem. @Rossitten I also found this.. https://dollarshaveclub.github.io/stickybits/

Comment: Thanks for the mention; very decent of you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly silly (but working well and, unlike all the mentioned above pure CSS solutions-  this one is a cross-browser one) solution with JQuery involved:

```
 // getting initial data
  var fixed = $('#fixed').width();;
  var main = $('#main').width();

  // getting left offset
  var leftSpace = $('#main').offset().left;

 // caltucating difference, dividing by two and adding left margin
  var diff = (main - fixed) / 2 + leftSpace;

  // updating CSS
  $('#fixed').css('left', diff);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PvfFy/983/